# On R720xd with H710p I want to delete a VD without reboot. MegaRAID Storage Manager gives me "this is an OS drive" and refuses

Tags: raid, dell, megaraid, h700

I'm trying to reorganize VD on Dell R720xd without reboot.

iDRAC queues VD deletion for reboot time. 
A hack with installing LSI MegaRAID Storage Manager GUI refuses to delete VD saying "this is an os drive"

The drive is not mounted anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns our I had to delete all signs of partition tables from the VD, mine was GPT so I used gdisk /dev/, then used options

```
Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): z
About to wipe out GPT on /dev/sdd. Proceed? (Y/N): Y
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using 
fdisk or other utilities.
Blank out MBR? (Y/N): Y
```

and then MegaRAID Storage Manager finally agreed to delete the VD..

UPD: + it took me some time to find a command for CentOS/RedHat to make fdisk realize the changed size of my /dev/sdd, the command is:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdd/device/rescan
```